# How to create a dynamic drop down list using a cell with comma separated values in google sheets via apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The script below allows me to automaticlaly create a dynamic dropdown list using namedranges i set up based on the value chosen on a cell

```
function depDrop_(range, sourceRange){
    var rule = 
    SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(sourceRange, 
    true).build();
    range.setDataValidation(rule);
    }
function onEdit (){
    var aCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell();
    var aColumn = aCell.getColumn();
    if (aColumn == 3 && SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()){
    var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(aCell.getRow(), 
                aColumn + 1);
    var sourceRange = 
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName(aCell.getValue()); 
    depDrop_(range, sourceRange);
    }
    else if (aColumn == 4 && SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()){
       var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(aCell.getRow(), aColumn + 1);
       var sourceRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName(aCell.getValue());
       depDrop_(range, sourceRange);
    }
    }
```

What I'm trying to do though is use a cell with comma separated values (instead of namedranges) for the dynamic dropdown list that I want to create automatically based on the chosen value on another cell. Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rW9T4XZy-7U&t=352s) on which this code is based. It is a very, very simple solution to a very, very, complex problem. My strong suggestion is that you to try and utilize the script, but to use your comma separated values as the input ranges.

I suggest extracting the csv values from the respective cells using this equation.

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(B3,","))
```

Use SPLIT to separate the individual elements in the cell. Then use TRANSPOSE to orient the data vertically. You could also throw in SORT, if the data was not in the "right" order.

---

[image: data validation use csv values]

The screenshot shows the values in a csv format; they are extracted and transposed using this formula. And then the range is named, as the YouTube video requires.

This really is the *easiest* way to create dynamic multi-dependant dropdowns